# Intellij idea - how to show more revisions in VCS history?

Tags: svn, version-control, intellij-idea

In intellij Idea, I see only about past 600 revisions in the Changes->Repository tab. Is there some way to increase this number? 
In the settings, I've unchecked

`Version Control->Limit history by:`

and set

`Version Control->Background->VCS History Cache Settings-> Changelists to cache initialy` to 5000

but after refresh of the VCS, I still see the same amount of revisions. 
The other options in the `Version Control` settings are unchecked except for `Notify about VCS root errors`

I use IntelliJ Idea 12.1.6 and VCS is SVN 1.7

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you click on refresh button of the

> Changes > Repository

tab the first time, it appears VCS History cache settings dialog box. Since this box, you are able to modify :

- Change lists to cache initially
- Refresh changes every ... minutes.

If you changes these two values, I think you can increase revisions in VCS history.

If this dialog box don't appers, you can change this values since Setting>Version control>background menu> section History cache settings

Once the change is done, clear the cache - click the red "X" on the VCS panel. Unless you did that, the change is not applied.
After that, click refresh again and your older revisions will appear.

Comment: It didn't help. I've also tried to remove the limit completely.

Comment: I'm not sure what was the problem. In another project it is working fine. I think it was some problem with SVN branches.

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj I'm also experiencing this.  I think this is a bug: If you change this setting, it doesn't get more when you do an update.

Comment: @tieTYT - You must clear cached revisions first. Look for a red X symbol to the right of the refresh button. Once cleared, refresh again.

Comment: in Intellij 2018 this is replaced with a trash bin icon