# android studio VCS local history too short

Tags: android, android-studio, version-control, revision-history

After I change to a new PC and install new Android Studio 3.4.1, I find the VCS-Local History is much shorter than before in my old PC. Now it keeps about only one month history. Before, it kept much longer for many months. How to fix this? Thanks in advance!

I've tried the solution in this post and it doesn't work.
[Intellij idea - how to show more revisions in VCS history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20496785/intellij-idea-how-to-show-more-revisions-in-vcs-history)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of my friends tells me this method:

In Android Studio, menu Help, click Find Action. 
Then input "registry" and find the item "localHistory.daysToKeep". Modify it to "180" (days, you can change the number for your demand).
After that, it can record history for many months now.

For more information https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html

Comment: My android studio version is 3.4,I remember that I can set day number in "Setting" two years ago.But now i can not find ,where do you know?

Comment: Maybe you're saying in Android Studio,menu File-Settings-Version Control, [Show changed in last ___ days]. I've tried that and it doesn't extend the history. You can try  it by yourself and tell me whether anything different.

Comment: this option is not found in the new version of AS

Answer (score 0):

In the recent version of Android Studio you'll find this setting at `Settings > Advanced Settings > IDE section`. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html#local-history-retention.