# How to change number of days to keep history in Android Studio Chipmunk

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, history, intellij-plugin

Accodring to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57345479/4205927), I wanna change the number of days to keep history for each project in Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 2, I tried to search in registery setting but it look the option **"localHistory.daysToKeep"** is deleted or moved in the new versions

[image: "localHistory.daysToKeep"]

Answer (score 0):

The option has been moved to advanced settings:
[image]

Comment: this not about local history, please see the edited link question